# New or Old Non-MVC PHP Frameworks

Tags: frameworks, php

I know this has been asked way too many times... But I am in search of a non-mvc-based PHP framework. My only requirements are that it be stable enough, and not one that can be easily found (meaning that if it can be easily found, then I've probably already found it, and don't like it)

Any help is appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: If you know this has been asked many times, why'd you ask it?

Comment: @Rafe: *My only requirements are that it be stable enough, and not one that can be easily found (meaning that if it can be easily found, then I've probably already found it, and don't like it)* - As I hinted in my question; I've already searched, couldn't find one I liked and am now asling if anybody else knows of anything **else** that's around somewhere...

Comment: You should clarify what you have already looked at, what you didn't like about it and what other qualities you're looking for. Otherwise this is quite hard to answer for mere non-psychics.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Fat Free](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/) - can be used in an MVC way or not - super flexible, but needs PHP 5.3+ to run.

Comment: Thanks @jpea, this one looks nice will give it a go

Comment: I like F3 too! Very nice for small, simple apps.